# R shiny: how to give an inputID to an actionButton created via HTML

Tags: html, r, shiny

If I create a .htlm file to define an actionButton, how can I give an inputID to the button (in order to do other things based on its value) ?

As you will see in the .html, I try to give it an "id" but it does not work. And I believe that actually giving an inputID should be done in the ui.R file.

Here are my UI, server, and .htlm file:

1/ui:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("test"),

sidebarPanel(),

mainPanel(
includeHTML("static.html"),
uiOutput("x")
)
))
```

2/server:

```
shinyServer(function(input,output){
output$x<-renderUI(h4(input$button1))            
})
```

3/static.html

```
<p> <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button" id="button1"><i class="icon-star"></i>Large button</button>

</p>
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Ok, sry for my 1st answer I misunderstood your pb. I never did that but I think you should look for how to bind inputs http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/#building-inputs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem is that your html is creating a plain vanilla "button", not a shiny "action button". If your goal is to create an action button with custom classes, you can do it with:

```
tags$button(id="button1", 
            type="button", 
            class="btn action-button btn-large btn-primary", 
            HTML('<i class="icon-star"></i>Large button'))
```

This is equivalent to a call to `actionButton(...)` but allows you to set the `class=...` attribute explicitly.

So this code produces a page with an action button styled as in your `static.html` file.

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI = pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("test"),
  sidebarPanel(HTML(paste('<p>Click Count: ',textOutput("count"),'</p>'))),
  mainPanel(
#    includeHTML("static.html"),
#    uiOutput("x"),
    tags$button(id="button1", 
                type="button", 
                class="btn action-button btn-large btn-primary", 
                HTML('<i class="icon-star"></i>Large button'))
  )
)
shinyServer = function(input,output){
 # output$x     <- renderUI(input$button1)
 output$count <- renderText(input$button1)
}

runApp(list(
  ui = shinyUI,
  server = shinyServer
))
```

As you can see, you can reference it in `shinyServer` using `input$button1`. I'd also recommend you load the most recent version of package `shiny`.

**EDIT** (Response to @JulienNavarre comment)

Turns out this works as well:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI = pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("test"),
  sidebarPanel(HTML(paste('<p>Click Count: ',textOutput("count"),'</p>'))),
  mainPanel(
        includeHTML("static.html")
  )
)
shinyServer = function(input,output){
  output$count <- renderText(input$button1)
}

runApp(list(
  ui = shinyUI,
  server = shinyServer
))
```

**IF** you change `static.html` as follows:

```
<button class="btn action-button btn-large btn-primary" type="button" id="button1">
   <i class="icon-star"></i>
      Large button
</button>
```

In other words, you have to include `action-button` in the class list, and remove the `<p></p>` tags.

Comment: True that it's a better practice to use the "tags functions" of shiny rather than include some HTML. However I'm really interessted in how you can "make" the id of the button in the external file understandable for shiny.

Comment: Thank you jlhoward ! This is what I was looking for. @JulienNavarre: I don't really understand what you're saying the comment ? Is there something else that one may want to do in an external file ?

Comment: @JulienNavarre - See my edits above. Turns out you can use included HTML.